# How to unit test integer parameters by passing string value in nunit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, nunit

Say, in a C# console app, there is a simple function like below-

```
    public int MaxValue(int? i1, int? i2)
    {
      if (i1>=i2)
          return i1;
      else
          return i2;
    }
```

I want to throw exception from Maxvalue() if a string is passed as parameter; the unit test function will be something like below-

```
    [Test]
    public void test1()
    {
      Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(()=> ob.MaxValue("A", "B"));
    }
```

But passing string as a parameter to MaxValue() in place of an integer is not possible. So, how do I test this?

Comment: `string` cannot be passed as `int?` parameter. Your question should be *'How do I unit test code which do not compile?'*

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy no. whether user gave a wrong input is one of my test cases. the example is just for simplicity. I want to prevent a user from doing that and test the code.

Comment: @JabinTonni so show your case. Unit test should test function. In your code you can't make int from "A" so code fails on convert "A" to int.

Comment: @JabinTonni no. This example is not for simplicity. It's a misleading example

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, it took me a while to understand your suggestion "how do I unit test code which do not compile". I found suggestions on using reflection. I'm just one day old in unit testing, so please excuse my example. Thank you so much for the advice.  I wrote the parameters as 'int?' as one of my other test cases was to pass a null value to the function. But my understanding is I should not try to modify the code to run my tests. If you suggest me an easier tutorial on reflection, that would be wonderful.

Comment: @BWA, thank you so much. I need to find out how to check for compilation error. Could you suggest me any way of doing it?

Comment: @JabinTonni just read compiler output ;-) during execution, no compilation errors may occur.

Answer (score 3):

C# is strong typed language so compiler checks all function params for proper types. Pass string as int parameter isn't possible. This test do for you c# compiler in compilation.